# git push azure master azure fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service, web-deployment

I am new to azure.

I am following starter instructions from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-python#configure-a-deployment-user.

I have closed some gaps in the instructions so far such as incomplete commands (missing <--%> for Bash in < az webapp create --resource-group myResourceGroup --plan myAppServicePlan --name < app_name> --runtime "python|3.4" --deployment-local-git>) or git init (needed before the command git remote add azure < deploymentLocalGitUrl-from-create-step>).

Now I am stuck at the step of the push to Azure remote to deploy the app. The command `<git push azure master>` with the current failure 
`PS Azure:\> git push azure master
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

I have checked the git status: it showed that there is no commit yet. 
Any suggestion?

I trust the procedure from Azure team and I am following it to the point. Any better resource or updated resource that I could rely to?

Comment: You will need to improve your question before you're going to get help. Provide a [mcve] and improve the grammar so that it is understandable.

Comment: @JCN if my solution helps, you could accept it as an answer or if you have further questions, just ask.

Comment: @JL: Thank you for helping. How do I accept? Issue solved now! I am not sure about the root cause. I simply resumed where I left when I experienced the fatal error.

Comment: @JCN on the left of my answer, you can see a grey √ , just click on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing git operation in Azure Cloud Shell, as `PS Azure:>` shows.

In the link you provide, you can see the guidance `Back in the local treminal window`.
[image: git tutorial]

Git related operation is used to deploy **local app** to Azure, so you have to use git bash locally to input your command.

After solved this, everything should work. As for better resource, if you mean deployment options, you can find other ways in the left side bar in your link.

[image]